# Replacing some URLs with another

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL 5.7.29 database on which a website is built. I need to construct a query to find all table rows containing lines such as

```
https://example.com/index.php?topic=7989.0
```

or similar and replace them with

```
https://example.com/my-redirect-page/?7989.0
```

The wildcard here is the ?topic=7989.0 as this can be something like ?topic=1234 or even ?topic=3456.0#anchor

I can display the rows they appear in (in PHPMyAdmin) using this (thanks to 'sticky bit' below) :

```
SELECT * FROM `abc_posts` WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%example.com\index.php?topic%'
```

My problem is that I then need to change just that URL when there is also text content around it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark doesn't need to be escaped.

But `'https://example.com/index.php?topic=7989.0'` isn't `LIKE '%example.com\?topic%'` as the question mark doesn't immediately follow the host name.

Try:

```
...
post_content LIKE '%example.com/index.php?topic%'
...
```

Comment: Thanks @sticky bit, I have updated the mistake in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something  like thin to find them

```
SELECT 'https://example.com/index.php?topic=7989.0'
WHERE 'https://example.com/index.php?topic=7989.0' REGEXP 'example.com/index.php?topic=';
```

Which would find all rows. But for replacing it, you must also tell which database version youh have mysql 5.x have not many regex fucntions mariadb and mysql 8 have much more

Comment: Thanks @nbk, I have updated the original post with MySQL version number.